# Trying to understand Windows power configuration APIs

Tags: c++, winapi, power-management

Can someone explain what is the difference between [PowerReadDCValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [PowerReadDCValueIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [PowerReadDCDefaultIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

I'm mainly concerned about "what is index"? And "what is default index"?

Answer (score 0):

consider the current Minimal power state is 10%.

the 1st function returns "10" string.

the 2nd function returns 10 (DWORD) index.

the 3rd function returns 5(DWORD) index.

Comment: You need to flesh out this answer so it corresponds to the questions.